# Tango compilation issues with mutex

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, google-project-tango

I'm trying to compile the Tango examples (from [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-c)) with Android Studio and the NDK, but I keep running getting the following error:

```
Error:(96, 8) error: 'mutex' in namespace 'std' does not name a type
```

from the line

```
std::mutex pose_mutex_;
```

I'm using the latest GitHub release with the necessary libraries included. I've checked the Android.mk file and see that it compiles with the c++11 flag and another simple C++ program I wrote compiles just fine with mutex.

I'm still starting with the Tango so I'm struggling with the debugging. Has anyone else had this issue? What am I missing?

Comment: Are you using r12?

Comment: @AlexCohn r12 of the Android NDK? As far as I can tell, only r11c has been released so far (revision history [here](http://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/revision_history.html))

Comment: Right, r12 is still in Beta, but it was by mistake pushed to the stable channel of Android Studio. The trick is that the first version of r12 that was pushed this way, had a regression directly related to std::mutex and std::thread.

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense, I see I actually did install r12 then. The workaround I posted below seems to be working without any issues so far, but I'll downgrade to r11c in the mean time to avoid any other confusing issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to answer my own question.

The `Application.mk` given in the example project has the line

```
    APP_STL := gnustl_static
```

Apparently this support library does not have Mutex support. Changing it to

```
    APP_STL := c++_static
```

seems to have fixed it and it compiles and runs happily now.